# How can I write a discord.py function that accepts integers, booleans, strings or None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to write a function in discord.py that accepts integers, strings, booleans or None as a parameter.

This is my code so far:

```
@commands.command()
async def post(self, ctx, type = ""):
    '''Post a random picture from the preselected gallery'''
    path = "A Folder that I want to keep hidden from the public HAHAHA ok..."
    x = 0
    if ctx.channel.is_nsfw() = True:
        await ctx.send("I'm sorry, but I can't post these kinds of pictures here!\nI can only post in safe for work areas. Server rules!")
        return
    if is_number(type):
        if type > 5:
            await ctx.send("I'm sorry, I cannot post more than 5 images.\nWe don't want me to be kicked for spamming images.")
            return
        while x < type:
            x += 1
            await ctx.send("", file=discord.File(path + "\\" + random.choice(os.listdir(path))))
    elif type == 'maxindex()':
        number_of_files = len([item for item in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, item))])
        await ctx.send(f'I found: {number_of_files} total files')
    else:
        await ctx.send("", file=discord.File(path + "\\" + random.choice(os.listdir(path))))
```

I would like to be able to do something like `;post 1`, `;post maxindex()` or `;post`. The commands with an integer or nothing will post that amount or one image (if None). The command with the 'MaxIndex()' string will allow to see how many "usable" images are in the folder.

If I'm not clear enough, please do ask me to clarify.

Comment: would using `isinstance( ..., int)` , `isinstance( ..., bool)` , `is not None` simplify it? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance

Comment: Aside, `if ctx.channel.is_nsfw() = True:` will not work, you need `==` to test for equality.

Comment: also I would not use `type` as a variable - its shadowing the inbuild  `type()` which is not critical here but a bad habit and can lead to confusion

Comment: @roganjosh I know that the == is needed, but I had to do a quick edit on the code and accidently removed the second equals sign

Answer (score 0):

(Eh, got too long to write my answer.)

> What I'm looking for is a way to allow Integers, Strings, AND Boolean into a parameter for a function.

You can just check if your value is what you expect it to be !

```
def example(myVar):
    if myVar is None:
        print("My parameter is None !")
    elif isinstance(myVar, int):
        print("My parameter is an Int !")
    elif isinstance(myVar, list):
        print("My parameter is a List !")
    else:
        print("Eh. Not something I want.")

example(None)
example(16)
example([1, 2, 3])
example("Hello")
```

Outputs :

- My parameter is None !
- My parameter is an Int !
- My parameter is a List !
- Eh. Not something I want.

Answer (score 0):

The `typing` module includes `Union[]`, which lets you automatically convert arguments to any of a list of pre-selected types. For example, you can do this:

```py
async def post(ctx, type : typing.Union[None,int,str,bool]):
```